# remove the records with a specific port number from a log file

Tags: text-processing

I have a log file but I want to remove the specific port data from the log file

The port number is `22696`.
 
Example log record like this:

```
  87.14.101.122   22696   2018-01-10 01:12:30 +0000       CONNECT gsp10-ssl.apple.com:443 HTTP/1.1        200     0       locationd/2236.0.11 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/17.2.0
```

Comment: you could add some more context lines to ensure that your log file has static lines format presentation

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `awk`:

```
awk '$2 !~ /^22696$/' file
```

This command checks second field (`$2`; spaces as delimeter by default) for exact matching (`/22696/`) from start position (`^`) to end position (`$`) and invert result (`!`).

Or simpler (thanks [RomanPerekhrest](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/148009/romanperekhrest)):

```
awk '$2!=22696' file
```

To safely edit your log file that may be large, try to use this command set:

```
mv file{,.backup} && awk '$2!=22696' file.backup > file
```

After this you may need to change the file permissions with `chmod`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`, you would define a pattern for those lines and invert the selection with option `-v`:

```
grep -v '^ *[^ ]* *22696 ' file
```

Comment: I have multiple posts data delete from the log file

Comment: Yes. So what? The given command removes all those lines with port 22696.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use below command to achieve the same

Inputfile ==> it consists 2 lines one line with 22696 entry and other line with 22697 entry.

Goal is to remove the line which consist of 22696

Inputfile

```
 87.14.101.122   22696   2018-01-10 01:12:30 +0000       CONNECT gsp10-ssl.apple.com:443 HTTP/1.1        200     0       locationd/2236.0.11 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/17.2.0
 87.14.101.122   22697   2018-01-10 01:12:30 +0000       CONNECT gsp10-ssl.apple.com:443 HTTP/1.1        200     0       locationd/2236.0.11 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/17.2.0
```

Command

```
sed -i '/22696/d' Inputfile
```

Output

```
87.14.101.122   22697   2018-01-10 01:12:30 +0000       CONNECT gsp10-ssl.apple.com:443 HTTP/1.1        200     0       locationd/2236.0.11 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/17.2.0
```

Comment: Explain your question please not able to understand. i have 2 lines as example first line contains 22696 my command will delete  line which contain 22696